# Proof that the elements are distinct with Peano's axioms.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, real-numbers, peano-axioms

Consider the function successor function $s: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ and the Peano's axioms:

P1) $s: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ is injective.

P1) $\mathbb{N} \setminus s(\mathbb{N})$ has only one element. That is, there is a single natural number that is not a successor to any other. It is represented by 1.

P3) (*Induction principe*) If $X \subset \mathbb{N}$ is such that $1 \in X$ and, for all $n \in X$ we have $s(n) \in X$ too, then $X = \mathbb{N}$.

Defining the n-fold composition $s^n= s \underbrace{\circ \ldots \circ}_{n \quad \text{times}} s$.

I would like to just use the axioms to show that the elements of set
$$A = \{1, s(1),  s^2(1), \ldots, s^n(1),\ldots\}$$
are distinct two to two distinct.

**Comments**: My first idea was to take two elements in $A$, one with an $m$ amount of compositions and the other an $n$ amount, but that doesn't seem to make much sense as the set is infinite and I think I would have to do induction (ie, use P3) somewhere.

Another idea is to call it $A_n=\{1, s(1), s^2(1), \ldots, s^{n-1}(1)\}$. Then, $s(A_n) \cup \{1\} = A_{n+1}$ and show by P3 that each $A_n$ have all elements distincts. But I don't know how I would write the $A$ from that.

Comment: What do you mean by showing that the elements of $A$ are distinct? Can you write this as a formal statement? Also, how exactly are you defining $A$?

Comment: Not being equal two by two, I don't know how the correct translation is in English.

Comment: So are you saying that for all distinct $x, y \in A$, that $x \neq y$? Because the problem with that is that saying "$x$ and $y$ are distinct" means saying $x \neq y$, so you're basically trying to prove that if $x \neq y$ then $x \neq y$.

Comment: You should mention that the element in P1) is denoted by $1$.

Comment: Yes, I will add in the statement. Thank you.

Comment: @PaulFrost Thank you, I added this in P2.

Comment: I do not think that your question makes much sense. Defining the $n$-fold composition  $s^n = s \circ \ldots \circ s$ requires an interpretation of $n$. This $n$ is an element of $\mathbb N$ which is defined by the Peano axioms, but it seems to me that you use an *intuitive* interpretation of natural numbers $n$ preceding their proper definition via the Peano axioms. In fact you have $n +1= s^n(1)$ which is circular. You should clarify this point.

Comment: @MarkSaving What I mean is that there are no two equal elements in A, not if that statement from before says so.

Comment: @PaulFrost I found this version like this in a text. But I agree with you, actually the set $A = \mathbb{N}$. So I think the problem should be to show that in $\mathbb{N} $all the numbers are distinct using the Axioms.

Comment: @Croos But there are two equal elements; $1 = 1$.

Comment: All distinct elements of a set (e.g. $\mathbb N$) are trivially distinct. So "to show that in $\mathbb N$ all the numbers are distinct using the Axioms" does not make much sense. The point is you  have to define $s^n$ **without** using an intuitive understanding of $n$.  That is, to each $n \in \mathbb N$ you have to assign a function $s^n$ without counting $\circ$'s. Try to use an inductive definition.

Comment: @MarkSaving It is in the sense of being two-by-two distinct.

Comment: @Croos You need to provide a formal definition of two-by-two distinct.

Comment: @MarkSaving $s^n(1) \neq s^m(1)$ if $m\neq n$.

Comment: @Croos Definition of $s^n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Peano Axioms imply the following statement:

There is an element $0 \in \mathbb{N}$ and a function $s : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ such that for all sets $A$, elements $a \in A$, and functions $t : A \to A$, there exists a unique function $f : \mathbb{N} \to A$ such that $f(0) = a$ and $f \circ s = t \circ f$.

Note: I'm using $0$ as the non-successor element rather than 1. This can be viewed as a purely notational difference, but in light of notation to be introduced shortly, I think it's the more natural choice.

Proof: Suppose the Peano Axioms, and consider $A, a \in A$, and $t : A \to A$. A partial function $g : S \to A$, where $S \subseteq \mathbb{N}$, is said to be an "attempt" if (1) for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, if $s(n) \in S$ then $n \in S$, (2) if $0 \in S$ then $g(0) = a$, and (3) for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, if $s(n) \in S$ then $g(s(n)) = t(g(n))$.

Claim: For all $x \in \mathbb{N}$, there exists a unique $y \in A$ such that there is some attempt $g : S \to A$ for which $x \in S$ and $g(x) = y$.

Proof: we proceed by induction on $x$.

Base case: $x = 0$. Take $y = a$. We see that the attempt $g : \{0\} \to A$ defined by $g(0) = a$. And by the definition of an attempt, if $g : S \to \mathbb{N}$ is an attempt and $0 \in S$, then $g(0) = a$.

Inductive step: suppose true for $n$. Let $q$ be the unique $q$ such that there is some attempt $g : S \to A$ with $n \in S$ and $g(n) = q$. Take some such $g$. Take $y = t(q)$. Define $g' : S \cup \{s(n)\} \to A$ by $g'(k) = g(k)$ if $k \in S$, and $g'(s(n)) = t(q)$. Note that in the event that $s(n) \in S$, we see that $g(s(n)) = t(g(n)) = t(q)$, so $g'$ is well-defined. And note that for any attempt $h : R \to A$ such that $s(n) \in R$, we have $n \in R$, thus $h(n) = q$, thus $h(s(n)) = t(h(n)) = t(q)$.

Now define $f(x)$ to be the unique $y$ such that for some attempt $g : S \to A$, $x \in S$ and $g(x) = y$. Note that $f(0) = a$ and that $f \circ s = t \circ f$. Finally, suppose we had some $f' : \mathbb{N} \to A$ also satisfying $f'(0) = a$ and $f' \circ s = t \circ f'$. Then $f'$ is an attempt, so for all $n$, $f(n) = f'(n)$. $\square$

With this in mind, we make the following definition:

> Suppose that $a \in A$, $t : A \to A$, and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $f : \mathbb{N} \to A$ be the unique function such that $f(0) = a$ and $f \circ s = t \circ f$. We define $t^n(a)$ to be $f(n)$.

With this in mind, we can now prove

> Theorem: the map $f(n) = s^n(0)$ is injective.

Proof: Consider the map $f(n) = s^n(0)$. This is the unique map satisfying $f(0) = 0$ and $f \circ s = s \circ f$. But there is also the map $1_\mathbb{N}$, defined by $1_\mathbb{N}(n) = n$, which satisfies $1_\mathbb{N}(0) = 0$ and $1_\mathbb{N} \circ s = s \circ 1_\mathbb{N}$. Therefore, $f = 1_\mathbb{N}$. And clearly, $1_\mathbb{N}$ is injective. So $f$ is injective.